# How to get exact time since iOS device booted?

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

I've encountered a problem. I need to get the exact TimeInterval since the device was booted. In the `CoreMotion` framework `CMLogItem` class have timestamp property, it returns exact time since device was booted. ([link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremotion/cmlogitem/1615939-timestamp)) This is necessary in order to measure the exact time for which the event occurred.

I tried the following code:

```
let timestamp = ProcessInfo.processInfo.systemUptime
```

but it returns different time than i need.
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigation of the data you provide. It is possible to conclude that `CMLog​Item`:

> The CMLog​Item class is a base class for Core Motion classes that
>   handle specific types of motion events. Objects of this class
>   represent a piece of time-tagged data that can be logged to a file.

CMLog​Item defines only a read-only timestamp property that records the time a **motion-event measurement was taken**. Not the exact time since device was booted.

By `ProcessInfo.processInfo.systemUptime` you going to get time from the last time it was restarted.

I believe data that you would like to obtain is quite specific and is under Private API of the iOS.

Comment: Thanks for response.

Comment: here https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremotion/cmlogitem/1615939-timestamp you can see that timestamp is amount of time since the device booted.

Comment: @AndreyM. thx for sharing of the info